# ASP.NET MVC 4 bundle with wildcard in folder path

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, bundle

My team uses a custom NuGet package for installing jQuery UI, which puts the theme files into a directory structure like this:

- Content

  - jquery-ui-1.10.3

    - images
    - jquery-ui.css
    - jquery-ui.min.css

I'm trying to use ASP.NET MVC 4 bundles to include this content in the BundleConfig class inside my application's App_Start folder like so:

```
bundles.Add( new StyleBundle( "~/bundles/css" )
                 .Include( "~/Content/normalize-{version}.css",
                           "~/Content/jquery-ui-{version}/jquery-ui.css",
                           "~/Content/Site.css" ) );
```

This throws an error when I run the site:

```
Directory does not exist.
Parameter name: directoryVirtualPath
```

I also tried:

```
bundles.Add( new StyleBundle( "~/bundles/css" )
                 .Include( "~/Content/normalize-{version}.css" )
                 .IncludeDirectory( "~/Content/jquery-ui-*", "*.css" )
                 .Include( "~/Content/Site.css" ) );
```

That doesn't work either (obviously). I can explicitly specify the version on the folder, but that defeats part of the benefit of using the bundle.

So how can I use a wildcard in the folder path?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the overloaded version of `IncludeDirectory` which searches subdirectories.

Suppose you have the following file:

`\Root\Content\jquery-ui-1.10.3\jquery-ui.css`

Use this code to find and add it:

```
.IncludeDirectory("~/Content", "jquery-ui.css", true)
```

This is useful because it will always find `jquery-ui.css`, regardless of where you put it.

The downside to this method is that it will search for and include **all** `jquery-ui.css` files that it finds, which could cause some bugs if you don't ensure that only one `jquery-ui.css` exists.

(Remember that searching for subdirectories will also still search the root directory i.e. ~/Content)

Comment: So there is no other option where we could specify the required file names instead of including all ??